# adding a user and selecting that user id from the DB in 1 query

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

What i would like to do is add a user to the DB. I have an id that auto-increments each time a user is added, but the problem is that i would like to get the id back from the user i just added and i would like to do it in 1 query. Anyone that can help me?

Comment: What language are you using to execute SQL statements?

Comment: mysql, forgot to add it, sorry

Comment: I mean the programming language eg: PHP, Java, Ruby etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you do with [mysql_insert_id()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php&ei=Rry1TcbSEIzFswaV18ngDA&usg=AFQjCNHkVdl9b6Ye8Qp9FwQlPGCxGuMnxA&sig2=la-7P1h04FqybcQBHd8X7Q)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```